# How to override a button attribute

Tags: android, xml, data-binding

I should be able to use a @BindingAdapter in Android dataBinding so that i can override a certain attribute. I am able to do it with a cusutom attribute but with a android built-in attribute how is it accomplished?

what i have so far:
in my viewModel i have a method that is annotated with @BindingAdapter and looks like this:

```
 @BindingAdapter({"android:text"})
    public static void setText(Button view,boolean language) {//i need to pass one more variable in here for area code , its just a integer, but how ?

        if("french".equals(language))//i want to test if french && area code
           view.setText("si vous play");
   else if ("English".equals(language)) //i want to test if french && area code
        view.setText("please");

    }
```

but i have a few problems. Lets see the xml :

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/mybutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{`french,844`}"/>
```

See my issue, i want to pass in more then one parameter to dataBinding. But how ? Do i have to make a POJO object and pass it in ? even if i did that how do i set the object from xml ?

So if someone can just tell me the following i'll be fine:
1. how to pass multiple values to a bindingAdapter and 
2. How to override a built-in android attribute in any view.

Comment: btw, "please" is "s'il vous plait" not "si vous play" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set two different values in your BindingAdapter, you should use two different attributes:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@{`french`}"
    app:areaCode="@{`844`}"/>
```

Then have two different attributes in your BindingAdapter:

```
@BindingAdapter({"android:text", "areaCode"})
public static void setText(Button view, String language, String areaCode) {
    ...
}
```

But it would probably be better to set a different "app:language" as that would be more clear to the developer.